how to alignment the different TYPEs that could be output from lsblk?
On some machines we get
lsblk -l
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda            8:0    0  180G  0 disk
sda1           8:1    0    1G  0 raid1 /boot
sda2           8:2    0  179G  0 raid1

on some others we get
lsblk -l
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda            8:0    0  180G  0 disk
sda1           8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
sda2           8:2    0  179G  0 part

and few others we get
lsblk -l
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda            8:0    0  180G  0 disk
sda1           8:1    0    1G  0 lvm /boot
sda2           8:2    0  179G  0 lvm

Our goal is to alignment the different TYPEs (as part/raid1/lvm) to part.
Here's an example of what we need:
lsblk -l
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda            8:0    0  180G  0 disk
sda1           8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
sda2           8:2    0  179G  0 part

What is the procedure to change the diff types to part?
Note - all possible options are: part, lvm, crypt, dmraid, mpath, path, dm, loop, md, linear, raid0, raid1, raid4, raid5, raid10, multipath, disk, tape, printer, processor, worm, rom, scanner, mo-disk, changer, comm, raid, enclosure, rbc, osd and no-lun.

Are all of those example outputs original (i.e. did lsblk actually output them with these exact types, names, and maj:min numbers) or have they been edited?
